# Check box sending value to next activity even after deselcting it

Tags: android, eclipse

I used a listview to display the check boxes in my activity. I also put a check to see atleast one check box is checked otherwise it will toast a message asking the user to please select atleast one value. Below are my two classes. Problem which i am having is that when i press the submit button without selecting a check box then i get a message to select atleast one checkbox. But when i select and deselect the check box and then submit it then it goes to the next activity with value of the check box which i dont want. It should not go to the other activity till i select one checkbox. Please help me with this problem.

**ConnectAdapter.java**

```
package com.arcadian.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

import com.arcadian.genconian.R;

public class ConnectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ConnectModel> {

    public ArrayList<ConnectModel> stateList;

    Context cntx;
    public static ConnectModel connect;
    CheckBox cb;

    public ConnectAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,

    ArrayList<ConnectModel> stateList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, stateList);
        this.cntx = context;

        this.stateList = new ArrayList<ConnectModel>();
        this.stateList.addAll(stateList);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        CheckBox connect_CB;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) cntx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_connect_row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.connect_CB = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.connect_CB);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.connect_CB
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            cb = (CheckBox) v;

                            if (v.isChecked()) {
                                connect = (ConnectModel) cb.getTag();
                                /*
                                 * Toast.makeText( cntx.getApplicationContext(),
                                 * "Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " -> " +
                                 * cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                 */

                                connect.setSelected(cb.isChecked());

                            }

//                          else{
//                          Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Select aleast one.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                          String select = null;
//                          }

                        }
                    });

        }

        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        ConnectModel state = stateList.get(position);

        holder.connect_CB.setText(state.getName());
        holder.connect_CB.setChecked(state.isSelected());

        holder.connect_CB.setTag(state);

        return convertView;
    }
}


**ConnectActivity.java**

package com.arcadian.genconian;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.arcadian.adapter.ConnectAdapter;
import com.arcadian.adapter.ConnectModel;
import com.arcadian.utils.CommonActivity;
import com.arcadian.utils.Constants;
import com.arcadian.utils.JSONParser;

public class ConnectActivity extends CommonActivity implements OnClickListener {

    ConnectAdapter dataAdapter = null;
    ArrayList<ConnectModel> stateList;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String to_connect;
    String response;
    private StringBuffer responseText;
    int success;
    String email, type;
    private String status;
    String select;
    ConnectModel _ConnectModel;

    ConnectModel selstate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect);

        // Generate list View from ArrayList
        displayListView();
        responseText = new StringBuffer();
        Button submit_BT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_BT);
        submit_BT.setOnClickListener(this);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        email = i.getStringExtra("user_email");
        type = i.getStringExtra("type");

    }

    private void displayListView() {

        // Array list of countries
        stateList = new ArrayList<ConnectModel>();

        _ConnectModel = new ConnectModel("All", false);
        stateList.add(_ConnectModel);
        _ConnectModel = new ConnectModel("Stream", false);
        stateList.add(_ConnectModel);
        _ConnectModel = new ConnectModel("Industry", false);
        stateList.add(_ConnectModel);
        _ConnectModel = new ConnectModel("Field", false);
        stateList.add(_ConnectModel);
        _ConnectModel = new ConnectModel("Batchmates", false);
        stateList.add(_ConnectModel);

        // create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
        dataAdapter = new ConnectAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                stateList);
        ListView to_connect_LV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.to_connect_LV);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        to_connect_LV.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        // openRequest.setCallback(statusCallback);
        // session.openForRead(openRequest);
        // loginProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        switch (id) {
        case R.id.submit_BT:

            ArrayList<ConnectModel> stateList = dataAdapter.stateList;
            response = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < stateList.size(); i++) {
                ConnectModel state = stateList.get(i);
                selstate = ConnectAdapter.connect;
                if(selstate!=null)
                if (selstate.equals(state)) {

                    select = "abc";

                    if ((stateList.size() - 1) >= i) {

                        responseText.append(state.getName() + ",");
                        String text = state.getName();
                        response = responseText.toString();
                        loge("response", "response text is" + responseText);
                    }

                    else {
                        responseText.append(state.getName());
                    }
                }

            }

            if (select == null) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select at least one.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                new Connect().execute();
            }
            /*
             * if(response.length()>1) {
             * if(response.substring(response.length()-1).equals(",") ) {
             * response
             * =response.replace(response.substring(response.length()-1), "" );
             * 
             * }
             * 
             * }
             * 
             * if (response.length() <= 1) { response =
             * "batch,stream,field,industry"; }
             */

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    public class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ConnectActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            to_connect = responseText.toString();

            String connect_url = Constants.REMOTE_URL + "/GenconianApi/reg2";

            log("to", "connect url is:" + connect_url);

            try {
                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                List<NameValuePair> Params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                String res;
                Intent email_Intent = getIntent();
                email = email_Intent.getStringExtra("user_email");
                type = email_Intent.getStringExtra("type");

                loge("email in", "connectactivity is:" + email);
                int len = response.length();
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {

                    builder.append(Character.toLowerCase(response.charAt(i)));
                }

                Params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                Params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("connected", builder
                        .toString()));
                Log.e("responce", builder.toString());

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(connect_url,
                        "POST", Params);
                loge("in reg2", json.toString());

                JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject("Status");
                loge("obj is", obj.toString());

                status = obj.getString("status");

                loge("user", "status is:" + status);

                success = Integer.parseInt(status);

                loge("chk", "rslt code is:" + success);

                if (success == 1) {

                    Intent k = new Intent(ConnectActivity.this,
                            FindFriends.class);
                    loge("chk", "inside success:" + success);
                    k.putExtra("user_email", email);
                    k.putExtra("type", type);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
                    startActivity(k);
                    loge("email", "" + email);

                    return json.getString(Constants.TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.e("Login Failure!",
                            json.getString(Constants.TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(Constants.TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            }

            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();

        Intent i = new Intent(ConnectActivity.this, More.class);
        i.putExtra("user-email", email);
        i.putExtra("type", type);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Move setOnCheckedChangeListener code out side if-else code in getView().

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the checkboxes in a Collection of checkboxes.

Upon clicking submit button, loop through all checkboxes to see anyone of them is checked at that moment

```
  Collection<CheckBox> boxes=new Vector<CheckBox>();

   ...

  public void onClick(View v){
      boolean anyoneChecked=false;
      for(CheckBox b: boxes){
         if(b.isChecked()){
             anyoneChecked=true;
         }
      }
      if(!anyoneChecked){
         return;
      }
      // go to next activity
  }
```